# terminate python multiprocessing pool cleanly

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing.pool to work with the http server in python - it works great, but when I terminate, I get a slew of errors from all the spawnpoolworkers - and I'm just wondering how I avoid this.

My main code:

```py
    def run(self):        
        global pool
        port = self.arguments.port
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool( processes= self.arguments.threads)
        with http.server.HTTPServer( ("", port), Handler ) as daemon:
            print(f"serving on port {port}")
            while True:
                try:
                    daemon.handle_request()
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print("\nexiting")
                    pool.terminate()
                    pool.join()
                    return 0
```

I've tried doing nothing to the pool, I've tried doing pool.close() - I've tried not joining.   But even if I just run that - never even access the port or call anything onto the pool, I still get a random list of things like this when I press control-c

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-8:

Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 365, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.1/F
```

how do I exit the pool cleanly, with no errors, and with no output?

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question, but I'll add on a related note that it's normally preferred to use a context manager (`with` block) for process pools to guarantee the cleanup process. Also, your code doesn't seem to actually use the pool, but I'm assuming you removed some complexity for the purpose of asking your question.

Answer (score 1):

ok - I'm stupid - the control-c was also interrupting all the child processes.  This fixed it:

```py
def ignore_control_c():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool( processes = self.arguments.threads, initializer = ignore_control_c )
```